# How to add vertices to OpenGL C++ triangle_fan

Tags: c++, opengl

I need to add correct lighting to an OpenGL irregular polygon that I filled using TRIANGLE_FAN.

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);

glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f,0.0f);
glVertex3f(b[0][0],b[0][1], 0);
glVertex3f(b[11][0], b[11][1], 0);
glVertex3f(b[7][0], b[7][1], 0);
glVertex3f(b[10][0], b[10][1], 0);
glVertex3f(b[6][0],b[6][1], 0);
glVertex3f(b[5][0],b[5][1], 0);
glVertex3f(b[4][0],b[4][1], 0);
glVertex3f(b[8][0],b[8][1], 0);
glVertex3f(b[3][0],b[3][1], 0);
glVertex3f(b[9][0],b[9][1], 0);
glVertex3f(b[2][0],b[2][1], 0);
glVertex3f(b[1][0],b[1][1], 0);
glVertex3f(b[0][0],b[0][1], 0);

glEnd();
```

The problem with my current polygon is that it does not reflect light correctly. It only does so from its vertices, which gives the light that hits it an X shape. I am guessing that I need to add vertices to my polygon. Is there a simple way to keep my triangle fan but add vertices to it?

Comment: Any chance I can convince you to use vertex buffer objects and shaders?  It will make your life so much easier going forward...

Comment: Idealy I would stick to what I have because of the short deadline I have and that then entire program is based on this structure..

Comment: I am not a great fixed pipleline guy - all my professional work has been with OGL_ES2 and above.  I'll defer to other on this.  I am honestly not sure how to get fragment lighting working in fixed pipeline.  Best of luck!

Comment: Well, if you don't want to use shaders and insist on using vertex color, you could implement denser geometry  but it will no longer be a triangle fan. But know this is the wrong way to do things, just as it is to use the fixed pipeline functionality.

Comment: VBOs (vertex buffer objects) and shaders are independent. If you insist on using immediate mode to render your geometry, you could still bind a fragment lighting shader before calling glBegin/End.

Comment: BTW, what platform are you targetting?  I see some ios tags in your past, but wanted to be sure for others...

Comment: This is a C++ program for PC use!

Comment: This question is very confusing. It's not clear what you mean by "add vertices to it". Add them *where*? What do you want the mesh topology to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get "correct" results when lighting your object, you need to define appropriate normals. Since you only have one normal for every vertex, it obviously didn't shade correctly.

However, there's no *correct* way to calculate normals for any model; you have to define *how* the object should be shaded, and then add more `glNormal` calls to inform OpenGL how you want it to be shaded.